# How Deadlock happens in the below code?

Tags: java

I have a simple code as below to test the deadlock

```
public class ClassB {
    public synchronized void fooB(Classs A) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.print("Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " entered to fooB \n");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print("ClassB locked the fooA \n");
        A.lastA();

    }

    public synchronized void lastB(){
        System.out.print("I am lastB \n");
    }
}
```

And Also I have another class called ClassA:

```
public class ClassA {
    public synchronized void fooA(ClassB B) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.print("Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " entered to fooA \n");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.print("ClassA locked the fooB \n");
        B.lastB();
    }

    public synchronized void lastA(){
        System.out.print("I am lastA \n");
    }    
}
```

So, now I have another code that calls these classes and causes a deadlock as below :

```
public class DeadLockTest implements Runnable {
    ClassA ca=new ClassA();
    ClassB cb=new ClassB();

    public DeadLockTest() throws InterruptedException{
        new Thread(this).start();
        ca.fooA(cb);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
             cb.fooB(ca);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ....

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the first thread locks fooB using **ca.fooA(cb)** and the second thread locks fooA using **cb.fooB(ca)** and **Nobody has any lock over lastA and lastB methods.** It means these methods are supposed to be available but they are not available. Why? The threads have just lock over fooA and fooB. So, why for example the first thread can't use lastB() and the second one has not access to lastA() while there is no lock on these two methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When used on a method, the `synchronized` keyword implicitly locks on `this` -- well, on the monitor associated with `this`. Objects have monitors; methods do not. So the monitor being used for `fooA()` is *the same monitor* being used on `lastA()`. That's why you have the deadlock.

Please read up on [`synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) before you go any further...

Comment: Indeed it is rather the intent that all the synchronized methods of a given class are exclusive for a given object. It would defeat the purpose if one thread could be 'inside' a modifying method while another thread were inside some read-only method. I agree with dcsohl. You haven't 'got it' until you 'get' that. It's the 'big idea' at the heart of developing concurrent programs using mutual exclusion (mutex) locks.

Answer (score 3):

This looks fairly straight forward. It's a typical circular shared resource scenario. A needs B to continue and B needs A to continue.

Locks:

```
Thread 1 -> ClassB -> ClassA
Thread Main -> ClassA -> ClassB
```

Processing Order:

1. From *Thread Main*, you start a new thread *Thread A*
2. *Thread A* acquires the lock for *ClassB*
3. *Thread Main* acquires the lock for *ClassA*
4. *Thread A* request the lock, and blocks, for the lock on *ClassA*
5. *Thread Main* request the lock, and blocks, for the lock on
   *ClassB*

Answer (score 0):

You are synchronizing the methods, so the lock object is the object in each case (ca and cb).

When the thread calls `cb.fooB(ca)` it grabs the lock object cb.

Then the main thread calls `ca.fooA(cb)` and so grabs the lock object ca.

But, the `fooA` method calls `cb.lastB()` in the main thread, and this method is anso synchronized, so the main thread tries to grab the lock cb, only to find that the other thread has the lock already, so it must wait.

In the meantime, the other thread has called `cb.fooB(ca)` which in turn calls `ca.lastA()`, so tries to grab the lock on ca, only to find that the main thread already has the lock, so it too must wait.

Result: each thread has a lock the other needs to proceed, so they wait for each other. Deadlock.